# If / Else Statement Conditions

Tags: javascript

I know that the following if / else statement would alert "The are not equal!"...

```
var a = 5, b = 10;

if (a !== b) {
    alert("They are not equal!");
} else {
    alert("They are equal!");
}
```

But what happens if I replace my condition with...

```
if (true) {
    alert("They are not equal!");
} else {
    alert("They are equal!");
}
```

My question is: what is the condition in the second example? 
It simply says "true" - what is this asking (what needs to be true)?? 
Does it mean that it returns 'true' *all* the time?

Comment: A condition is an expression that evaluates to a value.  In this case, the expression is `true`, which evaluates to `true`.

Comment: `and the first code block is always executed` Yep, it's not something you should see in real code - maybe while debugging, though

Comment: only first block will ever execute - I've used that pattern as a lazy debugging "switch" :p i.e. change true to false, and the second code block is run instead

Comment: Ok cool.. thx. One more question, though.. do the 'things' to be be evaluated have a name? For example, if it said: if (myVar1 != myVar2).. 
 does myVar1 and myVar2 have a name in relation to the if / else stament?

Comment: sorry.. I am very bad at explaining things... As a completely different example: If I did myVar1 + myVar2 . You would say that '+' is the operator and the variables are the operands- what about in conditional testing? Are they perhaps called Conditional Items (or something of the like)??

Comment: ...or would I jus say value one and value two?

Comment: *"being used"* eventually in JS schools. Where `//Second code block` should better be explained as: `//Second code block will never execute!`

Comment: @TheDemonHunter the *if*'s braces `()`, they **evaluate** the inner's statement code. `true` evaluates to... guess what?! `true`. Just like your `a !== b` evaluates to `true`. When true, only the first code block will execute. Hope it's clearer now. PS: this will also be useful to know: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: Yes, it certainly is clearer now... BUT.. if someone wrote 'true' as their first condition, what would be the point of having the if/else statement since second code block will never execute!!?

Comment: @TheDemonHunter read my pre-previous comment. Makes no sense. Since the second block will **never** execute.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan That's my point- it DOESN'T make sense.. so realistically, does this mean having 'true' as a condition is not something that should be done (except for debugging)?

Comment: @TheDemonHunter exactly. One day when you'll be a professional hardcore JS developer, I hope I won't stumble upon such examples in your book ;) For debugging purpose a common thing is to use ***environment variables*** say like: `App.env.development = true; // set to false when in production!` and than throughout the app logic you can find pieces like: `if (App.env.development) { /*some development code here*/ } ` - but that's entirely different from the plain simple hardcoded `if (true) { }`

Comment: There should be a function that returns true or false within the if condition otherwise you second code block is useless.

Comment: @ Roko C. Buljan ahhhh (lightbulb moment)!

Comment: @TheDemonHunter so basically, `if(true){alert("YEY!!");}else{alert("flz");}` is exactly the same as writing only this one line of code: `alert("YEY!!");` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The condition you will define, the most common is comparisons.

Example:

```
if(file.size > 100) { // will not be true always, it's depends of each specific file size
  alert("Your size file is bigger than permitted!");
} else {
  alert("Your file loading...");
}
```

2. On your code, first if condition block is always executed because you are setting true always. In real life we do normally do a comparison of values and conditions:

Remove **`true`** from your code and **put a comparison condition**.

Example:

```
var a = "ok";
var b = "ok";
var c = "other text";

if(a==b){ // will be true
  alert("first condition will execute a code");
} else { 
 alert("not executed");
}

if(a==c){ // condition will be false
  alert("not executed");
} else { 
  alert("else will execute a code...");
}
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you're right, i edited the code, thank you!